# How to check user is within given Country or not using reverse geocode. "HereMap Reverse Geocode"

Tags: reverse-geocoding, heremaps

I want to get reverse geocode of Here map to fetch user postalCode with specified Country. So, if user is not in that Country, it should give error/warning message.

Answer (score 0):

How about enabling the parameter `show`->`countryInfo` on the request so that we receive the country info in the response, and then do your own client-side checking for that country? https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html